# ' .lck' file gives NoSuchFileException in maven jar

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm trying to create a jar file from my project where I use `java.utils.logging` and I'm getting NoSuchFileException when running the jar with **"java -jar .\RideShare-2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar"**.

The `\logs` folder does exist and the code is running perfectly when I run it without a jar file.

What did I do wrong?

#### error

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: data\logs\log.0.lck
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:121)
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:298)
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:357)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:512)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:378)
        at utils.logs.LogHandler.<clinit>(LogHandler.java:42)
        at app.Main.init(Main.java:108)
        at app.Main.main(Main.java:69)
```

#### Logger file

```java
public class LogHandler{
    public static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LogHandler.class.getName());
    public static ConsoleHandler CONSOLE_HANDLER = new ConsoleHandler();;
    public static Handler FILE_HANDLER;

    static{
        LOGGER.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.ALL);

        try {
            //file handler
            FILE_HANDLER = new FileHandler("data/logs/log", 20000, 10);
            FILE_HANDLER.setFormatter(new LineFormat());
            FILE_HANDLER.setLevel(Level.ALL);

            //console handler
            CONSOLE_HANDLER.setFormatter(new colorFormat());
            CONSOLE_HANDLER.setLevel(Level.ALL);

            //add custom handlers
            LOGGER.addHandler(FILE_HANDLER);
            LOGGER.addHandler(CONSOLE_HANDLER);

        } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

#### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.finalProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>RideShare</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>app.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
    .
    .
    .
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: `data/logs/log` is a relative file name.  Whether it exists will depend on the [current directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of the Java process.  Unless you are explicitly changing to a particular directory every time you run your Java program, the real location of data/logs/log is *not* guaranteed.

Comment: so how can I fix it?

Comment: You can fix it by using a known location, instead of blindly hoping that the current directory is writable.  The current user’s home directory is usually a good choice;  for example, `System.getProperty("user.home") + "/data/logs/log"`.  Also, make sure the parent directory exists using [Files.createDirectories](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)).